# File Life access program in C using Linux platform

Tags: c

I have made a program in C which is used to delete a file in Linux but I want to apply timer in background for example files will be delete after 5 minutes or 10 minutes or any specified time which is given by the programmer so what should I do for implement a time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is implying   _"Please write my code for me."_  [On-topic Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. :-) Please show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)? You haven't actually explained your problem very clearly. Too many unknowns on the requirements of what your desired solution is.

Answer (score 1):

You should start a thread, which sleeps a while, then deletes the file.

- You can use C++ *thread class*, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/
- Or, in plain C, the *pthread* library https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PthreadsAPI
- Probably you've already used `sleep()` before.

Anyway, deleting a file does not affect on already opened files. You can try it in command line, launch two terminals, one with `cat >/tmp/myfile`, and another with `rm /tmp/myfile`. The `cat` will not die upon deleting the file.

Maybe, it's better to rethink this question: what is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to read the file timestamp using `stat` system call and then keep checking with your current system time, using `select`, `poll` or other event based libraries. When they exceed a certain value, you proceed to `unlink` that file.

And ofcourse you do that in a thread or another process.

Refer `man 2 stat` and `man 2 unlink`